# Which distro of Linux is best suited for Java web apps?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, hosting, alfresco

There are so many Linux distributions to choose from!  What is the "best" linux flavor for a web hosting environment running primarily:
Apache HTTP, Tomcat or JBoss, MySQL and Alfresco (not necessarily all in the same instance).

Are there any significant differences in terms of ease of administration and configuration, performance and stability for such applications, etc.?

What would you recommend?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They all use similar tools to administer things like webmin, and sshd.

What are you more familiar with. Red Hat based systems(fedora, mandriva) or Debian based systems(Ubuntu). This family divide will determine a few things. First rpm packaging vs deb packaging.

You also want to look at the level of activity of the project. Mandriva and Ubuntu are two examples of active distributions. That try to keep up with current releases of software.

Other than that most stuff performs with little difference.

Answer (score 4):

You also might want to consider [OpenSolaris](http://opensolaris.org/), as it is from the same company which developed Java in the first place and I've heard rumours, that it supports threading better than Linux does and in Java threads are quite important.

Update: Since Oracle changed the distribution model of OpenSolaris to a more commercial one you might want to check out the open source fork [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/) (thanks to sed for bringing this to my attention). Oracle seems to still be providing the non-open Solaris and does also own Java, so decide for yourself.

Comment: Opensolaris is no longer being developed according to wikipedia: "After the acquisition of Sun Microsystems in January 2010, Oracle decided to discontinue the OpenSolaris distribution and the development model. As a result, the OpenSolaris community forked as the OpenIndiana project, a part of the Illumos Foundation."

Comment: The power of Solaris systems is awesome, but it is not a very common Operating System, so some third-party tools might have not been recently built into a binary format for Sun/Oracle servers. That means that installing some third-party components might require to compile and build your own version from source code.

Answer (score 3):

No, not really.

It is really more down to the packages you install than the distribution you run.

For stability people always recommend Cent OS because it's the poor mans RHE (as in it's basically RHE but free-as-in-beer)

Comment: Yes. I have tried multiple distributions, and I think that CentOS has been the best I have found, and the one I'm currently using. It worked very well as a Virtual Machine both on VirtualBox and VMWare. I'm not saying that Ubuntu or Suse are not good distributions (perhaps with more experience I would be able to iron out the issues that I came across with).

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what tools (particularly commercial) you're using. Most Linux stuff is shipped for RHEL (Redhat Enterprise Linux) so you are usually best off using that. Centos is a free distribution based on RHEL (in fact it's almost identical) so a given vendor's stuff usually works the same there.

It also depends on hardware support. If you're using (for example) Dell servers, they support RHEL, but probably not e.g. Ubuntu so you really want to use a distro which is supported by your hardware vendor or their tools may not work.

It's not a case of "best" for hosting web applications, but for use in a commercial hosted environment. We use Centos so we can use RHEL stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I've generally been fine with plain old Debian (Ubuntu has its caveats that sometimes hit you at wrong times). Granted it requires a bit of configuration upfront but once there, its stable as anything. I generally don't use repositories unless they're very general stuff but rather compile things myself from the deb packages. It gives a bit more control over what you really want to do with your system and you can optimize to a certain extent. Currently, I'm running Tomcat 6 on Debian for some months without any big problems.

However, I think the debian family is much more friendly to implement even things that you don't really have much idea on or if you want to implement something fast or if you're trying out something in the site. In an ideal world, I'd do testing in a different machine or chroot, but hey I'm just a lazy sysadmin at times :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with a complete Sun stack and it seems to be working well so far.

- OpenSolaris
- Glassfish
- MySQL

I deploy .war files developed in Groovy with Grails but there are more and more options for deploying PHP and Ruby solutions. If cost is important, Sun is getting very aggressive partnering with hosting companies to provide free hosting for one year. I haven't had many obstacles but sometimes I have to look up command syntax since I hadn't used Solaris before.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned running Alfresco. You should look at the [Supported Platforms page](https://www.alfresco.com/services/subscription/supported-platforms) for the version you are planning on installing (even if you are installed Community Edition).

Most people running Alfresco use either Ubuntu Server or CentOS/Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Linux and Java. You did *not* mention other things like an Appserver, LDAP server, DB Server.

With those things considered, you would be best off with Redhat, Fedora, CentOS and SUSE/OpenSUSE. Ubuntu will not hurt since they have a relationship with Sun but since JBoss has become part of REdhat, I would think that Redhat-based distros should be pretty good.

I've used Redhat/Fedora and OpenSUSE to run banking production apps and they are pretty good. Dell offers good support for Redhat + JAVA + ORACLE.